# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate() updates the wrong entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm calling the following Mongoose function:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  '76561198015207414', 
  {}, 
  { upsert: true }
);
```

My `user` collection is empty before calling this.  After running the function, my `user` collection adds this document:

```
{
    "_id": 76561198015207410
}
```

Why would it be updating the wrong entry in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the `_id` that you've defined for `User` is a Number:

```
var UserSchema = Schema({
    _id : Number,
    /* more */
});
```

If you use JavaScript and convert the `String` passed to the call to `findByIdAndUpdate` and convert it to a `Number`, you'll see the precision isn't retained:

```
> var x=76561198015207414
> x
76561198015207410
```

You'll see the variable `x` contains the `_id` you've shown in your question.

You'll need to either switch to `String`s or be sure that the numbers do not exceed a `Number`.